# Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method share on channel plugins.flutter.io/share)

Tags: flutter, dart, share

Today I got this error when I test the new functions of my App

```
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:17968/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1555:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:40192:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:40062:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:34983:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:35551:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:35589:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:35437:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:35458:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:17968/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

I googled it and found another forum entry about the problem. They say the error appears, wehn a hot reload was confirmed. They say that I sould stop the app and re run it, but it doesn´t fix the error. The code is from a tutorial and there all workes fine.
Here is my Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const DetailScreen(this.title, this.done);
  final String title;
  final bool done;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: done ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Detail Screen'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 70),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      done ? 'Das hast du schon erledigt:' : 'Das musst du noch machen:',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white), textAlign: TextAlign.center,))
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, color: Colors.white)))
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 60,
                    onPressed: () {
                      String message;
                      if (done) {
                        message = 'Ich habe folgendes Todo erledigt: ' + title;
                      } else {
                        message = 'Das muss noch erledigt werden: ' + title;
                      }
                      Share.share(message);
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 60,
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    icon: Icon(done ? Icons.check : Icons.close, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

oh and sometimes IntelliJ forward me to a class named "binding.dart" and mark the line `completer.complete(reply);`. But I don´t know, what it will say me with this. The package I use for the share function is [this](https://pub.dev/packages/share)

Comment: Force Stop the running app, do `flutter pub get`, `invalidate cache & restart`.

Comment: how do I do the second step?

Comment: Assuming that you are using `Android Studio`, go to the `pubspec.yaml` & Click on `Pub get`, if using `VSCode` then use the command in the terminal.

Comment: on what device you are running the app?

Comment: I use chrome (Web) but with a resulution of a Iphone X

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue when I added a new dependency on my projet, and this is how I solved.

Stoped the app
ran `flutter clean`
ran  `flutter pub get`
Started the App and the error was gone.

Answer (score -1):

as you mention

I googled it and found another forum entry about the problem. They say the error appears, wehn a hot reload was confirmed. They say that I sould stop the app and re run it, but it doesn´t fix the error. The code is from a tutorial and there all workes fine.

not work for you try to run flutter clean & flutter pub get

Comment: It doesn´t work for me I clean flutter and run the command to get the pub. Now I don´t get any errors in the debug window, but when I click the Icon IntelliJ opens a file names `binding.dart` and mark the line `completer.complete(reply);` green.